# Connect to SVN repository with Netbeans using SVN+SSH

Tags: svn, java

I am trying to connect to a SVN server in order to import my project into it with svn+ssh authentication method. I am using the NetBeans IDE (6.8) with subversion plugin installed on Windows XP SP2. I have plink installed with its path set in the Windows PATH env variable. When I use the similar looking repository URL (XXXX and YYYY replaced with sensible things)

```
svn+ssh://XXXX@YYYY/home/dce/svn/trunk
```

along with this external tunnel command

```
plink -l <myUserName> -i C:\\privateKey.ppk
```

I keep getting this error:

```
org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: Network connection closed unexpectedly
```

I searched about it on the Internet and tried many things but didn't work out. Please help if anybody has some idea what may be going wrong. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar problems, but now I tried this:

1. remove the username part from the repository url (use svn+ssh://YYYY/home/dce/svn/trunk in your case);
2. use / instead of \ in the path to private key (C:/privateKey.ppk), using quotes if the path contains spaces.

This two steps worked for me!